# Why does VirtualWire seem to receive transmission twice?

Tags: arduino

I have a simple setup with two Arduinos and a 433MHz transmitter and a receiver module.

The transmitter is set to transmit a string on button press, that side works correctly.

On the receiver end I have a simple program that's just writing whatever it's receiving to serial:

```
#include "VirtualWire.h"

int rx_pin = 2;
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("serial ready");
    vw_set_rx_pin(rx_pin);
    vw_setup(2000);
    vw_rx_start();
    Serial.println("receiver ready");
}

void loop(){
    uint8_t msg[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t msglen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;
    vw_wait_rx();
    if(vw_get_message(msg, &msglen)){
        Serial.print("Got: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < msglen; i++)
        {
            Serial.print(char(msg[i]));
        }
        Serial.println();
    }
}
```

When I then monitor serial, the receiving Arduino seems to receive the message twice each time it's sent. I used an oscilloscope to verify (to the best of my knowledge) that the transmitter is only sending the message once, I also tried wiring the two Arduinos together to make sure the issue is not with the RF modules, I got the same results.

This makes me think there is an issue with my code or with VirtualWire itself.

I'm thinking that I should somehow check if I've received the same message already or I should clear VirtualWire's buffer, how would I do either of those?

EDIT:
Here is the transmitter code:

```
#include "VirtualWire.h"

int tx_pin =2;
int interruptPin = 3;
volatile bool transmitBool = false;

void setup(){
    vw_set_tx_pin(tx_pin);
    vw_setup(2000);

    pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), transmit, LOW);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    transmitBool = false;
}

void loop(){

    if(transmitBool) {
        transmitBool = false;

        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

        vw_send((uint8_t *)"abc", 4);
        vw_wait_tx();

        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    }
}

void transmit() {
    transmitBool = true;
}
```

Comment: Did you work this out yet? If not Can you show the transmitting code too please.

Comment: Not yet unfortunately, I updated the question with the transmitting code

Comment: I wonder whether the interrupt pin is bouncing?  Could you try calling transmit() on a timer e.g. delay(1000), then transmit, rather than using an interrupt?

Comment: @JeffUK you're right, it is probably the interrupt bouncing since without the interrupt it works exactly as expected. Thanks for the tip!